# Array of CFUUIDs?

Tags: ios, uuid

Here's my code:

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheralManager central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
{
    [self.centralManager retrievePeripherals:@[central.UUID]];
}
```

I get an error:

```
Collection element of type 'CFUUIDRef' (aka 'const struct __CFUUID *') is not an Objective-C object
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem:**

The compiler only knows about types, not about runtime behavior. It doesn't know that - most probably - `CFUUIDRef` can be used just like any normal Objective-C object (although it doesn't officially have a toll-free bridged Foundation class counterpart). It only sees that `const struct __CFUUID` is not an Objective-C class, and it bails out.

**The solution:**

I. <s>I presume this will work</s> - just tried it and it indeed works, `CFUUID` even has a nice description when printed using `NSLog().` However, it is not documented. Just cast it to `id`, like this:

```
@[(__bridge id)central.UUID]
```

II. Yes, you can convert it to a string, but that won't make the compiler error go away either - you do need that typecast, because the compiler quirks about the incompatible **types:**

```
CFStringRef uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault,@[central.UUID]);
NSString *uuidNSString = (__bridge NSString *)uuidString;
```

Now this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: To mess with you, there have a +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to convert it to an NSString and add that to the array.

```
+ (NSString *)convertUUID:(CFUUIDRef)theUUID
{
    CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
    CFRelease(theUUID);
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)string;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I focused on the type problem, the true problem is the fact of adding CF items into an nsarray.

I had my blinders on, ignore my response. But it is useful if you do need to convert at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting it to a Objective-C Object:

```
CFStringRef uuidString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, yourUUID);
NSString *uuidNSString = (__bridge NSString *)uuidString;
```

And if you need it back:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, uuidString);
```

Comment: Watch your second arg in CFUUIDCreateString. Also in the first line you are still in CF. Still not an object. See my answer below for full conversion.

Comment: Ins't that your CFUUID?